# How can I get the response status in actix-web middleware?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am using actix-web 3. I would like to access the current status code from within Actix-web’s middleware system.

I would like to modify the request based on the `StatusCode`, is this possible?

For instance if the user sends some data that causes actix-web to generate the 413 code, I would like to modify the Request.
I can modify the `Response` by the use of a handler of `ErrorHandlers` but these handlers only have `mut res: ServiceResponse<B>` as their arguments and it seems I am unable to find a way to access `ServiceRequest` object from within these handlers.

I would like to result to using basic middleware as the `ServiceRequest` and `ServiceResponse` objects are available in the middleware.

Answer (score 1):

The status code can be obtained by the use of the `.status()` method of the `HttpResponse` object from within the middleware code.
The code that implements the `Service` trait has access to the `HttpResponse` as shown below.

Since the status is generated after sending the request, there is no way to know the status before hand so as to modify the request.

```
let fut = self.service.call(req);

Box::pin(async move {
    let res = fut.await?;
    println!("Hi from response, res.status is:'{}'", res.status());
    Ok(res)
})
```